# Angular velocity required to hit a target

Tags: physics, velocity, target, angle

I'm stuck with this seemingly easy problem, but I can't wrap my head around it. I've tried solving this using the formulae given on the Wikipedia article on circular segments, but I must be missing something, so I kindly ask for you help.

We're in 2D. I have a point mass whose orientation is known. It is moving forward (and can only move forward, not laterally) with a fixed (and known) velocity. I also have a point target whose position relative to my point mass is known. I would like to know the angular velocity required for my point mass to hit the target.

Comment: Are you trying to solve this with a program? If so, please show the code you have so far. If not, then it's off-topic here.

Comment: Well, it's meant to be part of a simple racing AI, so there's code involved, but for this particular problem I don't have any code yet.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about physics / mathematics instead of directly about programming / coding / programming tools / software algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who cares, the solution appears to be

angular speed = Sin(ArcTan2(dx, dy) * 2) * (speed / dz)

where dx and dy are the target's coordinates relative to the point mass.